# Error in initializing the instance of a structure to NULL

Tags: c

I was writing a program to implement BST and I declareed two structures for that.

```
struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node *link[2];
};

struct tree
{
 struct node *root;
};

typedef struct node node;
typedef struct tree tree;
```

And then i wrote a function to insert the elements in it.

```
void insert_iter(tree *tree, int data);
```

But in my main() function, I got confused that what thing shoud I initialise as NULL. So, I did this in my main() function.

```
tree *tree=NULL;
```

And it gave an error of segmentation fault.
But then I realised that the first condition in my insert_iter() function calls for tree->root, so this error was bound to happen.

But then I am confused about how to initialize this. How to go on for this?

***EDIT: I have updated with the required code!!***

this is the main() function

```
int main()
{

tree *tree=NULL;  // all the confusion is regarding this

printf("hello");   // for debugging
//*tree->root=NULL;  // tried this one but it was wrong
int value,choice;
while(1)
{
    printf("enter the element : ");
    scanf("%d",&value);

    insert_iter(tree,value);

    printf("do you want to enter more : 0 or 1 : ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    if(choice==0)
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

and this is the function that i used to insert the elements

```
void insert_iter(tree *tree, int data)
{

if(tree->root==NULL)
    tree->root=newNode(data);  // function to make a new node
else{

node *it=tree->root;
int dir;
while(1)
{
    dir=data>it->data;
    if(it->link[dir]!=NULL)
        it=it->link[dir];
    else
    {
        it->link[dir]=newNode(data);
        break;          
    }
}}}
```

Comment: Please pick a language and stick with it instead of tagging two unless the question involves interop between the two

Comment: You should probably post the relevant code (`main()` and `insert_iter()` at the very least).

Comment: @EOF I have updated it with the required code!!

Comment: @Mgetz okay, but can you help me with this problem?

Comment: The first time you call `insert_iter()` in `main()`, you call it with a `NULL` tree* argument. In `insert_iter()` you dereference the tree* argument with `if(tree->root...)` without checking `if(tree!=NULL)`. SEGFAULT.

Comment: @EOF that's my question that when the tree is NULL, how should i go on to point the root of the tree to a new node!! I know the cause of segfault as i have mentioned in the question , i am asking the way to remove it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
tree *tree=NULL;  // all the confusion is regarding this

// the above is setting a pointer to NULL, which is ok


*tree->root=NULL;  // tried this one but it was wrong

// the above is setting a 
// (not initialized to point to any specific memory) 
// offset in the tree struct variable 
// (that offset is not pointing any specific memory)
// to set the first 4 bytes of that memory to NULL
// which should/will cause a seg fault event due to undefined behaviour 

// a workable solution might be:

tree *pTree = malloc( sizeof(tree) );

// and then this would work:

tree->root = NULL; // notice no '*' dereference needed

//I would also strongly suggest that the variable names be different 
//than the struct names, and not just in the capitalization of the name.  
//The use of different names will greatly enhance
//the readability and understandability and clarity of the code 
//(and will avoid any misunderstandings by the compiler and future maintainer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, got it!! I was making a mistake in not allocating the memory for tree.